# Using API token to access the CPanel UAPI returns access denied

Tags: cpanel, cpanel-uapi

I am trying to dynamically create email accounts for users via the CPanel API. According to the documentation [here](https://api.docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/tokens/), an access token can be used to call the API endpoints. I have an access token generated already but I keep getting acccess denied. I already tried generating another access token just incase the first one was wrong but Its still the same error.

My curl command is in this format as specified in the docs:

`curl -H'Authorization: cpanel username:U7HMR63FHY282DQZ4H5BIH16JLYSO01M' 'https://example.com:2083/execute/Email/add_pop?email=newuser&password=12345luggage'`

What could I be doing wrong please ?

Comment: Same issue - did you ever find a solution?